# Cannot load view using NSNib

Tags: swift

Anyone knows the correct way to instantiate a view using NSNib in Swift ?

The code below crashes.

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var myview:NSView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let obj = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray?>()
        if let success = NSNib(nibNamed: "View", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())?.instantiateWithOwner(self, topLevelObjects: obj) where success {
            if let m = obj.memory { // fatal error:
                myview = m[0] as! NSView
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this question?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the `fatal error` there because the value you are trying to access is nil and you are forcefully trying to unwrap the optional. You should safely unwrap optionals this is what they are meant for. So, always use `if` statement when you try to access optionals, then you won't get this error.

Comment: Did you actually try that ? It does not work like you expect. It's not Optional's issue. Even if you use `if let` , it occurs fatal error.

Comment: Edited to unwrap optional safely.

Comment: can you tell me what's the error I mean show your full error, what is exactly coming there?